# Getting the total video memory size

Tags: c, opengl, nvidia

On the internet I have found that there are OpenGL extensions for AMD and NVIDIA to get the memory information of the graphics card. Now I'm trying to get the total video memory size but I'm always getting 0 as a result. This is the current version of my code:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    GLint total_memory;

    total_memory = 0;
    glGetIntegerv(0x9048, &total_memory);
    printf("%i\n", total_memory);
    return 0;
}
```

The operating system is Linux and the NVIDIA driver version is 313.30.

Comment: You might want to consider using the library GLEW to handle extensions, using a constant like 0x9048 is not very readable! You will need to get the value of GL_GPU_MEM_INFO_TOTAL_AVAILABLE_MEM_NVX and GL_VBO_FREE_MEMORY_ATI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check with [`glGetError()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glgeterror) if a call seems to be failing.

In your case, I think you need a valid [OpenGL context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Context) before you can call OpenGL functions.

Comment: Interestingly glGetError() is returning 0 even without a context. My goal is simply to know if these vendor specific OpenGL extensions are working correctly on a current Linux system. I will for now assume that this is true. If I have more time I will maybe make a more detailed reading into this.

Comment: NVidia extensions work fine , I use those both on Linux and Windows

Comment: I have additional extended GPU card, Then glGetIntegerv(0x9048, &total_memory); returns only extended GPU details in dedicated memory etc., but not combination of both inbuilt and extended ,why ?

Answer (score 0):

On this post you can see 3 links given by the author helping to get what you want.

It seems that it depends a lot of what kind of graphic card you use and the version...

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/3347